# PICKIT 3 and 16F684 in-circuit debugger

Tags: pic, pickit, header

I am not sure which other parts (except PIC KIT 3) do I need for in-circuit debugging of PIC 16F684...

Do I need additional ICD header?

What about RJ-11 adapter/cable to connect PICKIT and header? Do I need one or is it included with header?

Is it possible to use in-circuit debugging functionallity without those two parts (is there any other way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPLAB will tell you if the 16F684 needs a separate debug header - select the device using Configure > Select Device. You should see that you need an [AC162055 header](http://www.microchipdirect.com/productsearch.aspx?Keywords=AC162055). The [product web page](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010214) also mentions it. It comes with an RJ11 connector, so you will need an adapter to use it with a PICkit.

The only debugging you will be able to do without the header is by using the simulator, or by inserting debug statements into your code and using a serial connection to your PC.